# Image tag showing error in react native after I imported the image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

the Image tag is showing error after I successfully imported the Image

there is a my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {View ,Image,Text } from 'react-native';



    export type AlbumProps = {
        id:string,
        ImageUrl:string,
        artistsHeadline:string;
      }
      
      const AlbumComponent = (props: AlbumProps) => {
      <View>
          
          <Image />
          
      </View>
        
      
      }
```

here is the error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ImageProps | Readonly<ImageProps>): Image', gave the following error.
    Property 'source' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<ImageProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ImageProps, context: any): Image', gave the following error.
    Property 'source' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<ImageProps>'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(3980, 5): 'source' is declared here.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the required property `source`:

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'http://url' }} />
```